# Difference between add and measured SNR in image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, noise

I am trying to add noise of 5dB to an image in matlab according to the following steps

```
SNR = 5;
Im = double(Io) / 255;
vm = var(Im(:)) / 10^(SNR/10);
I_my_noisy = imnoise(Im, 'gaussian', 0, vm);
```

but when I measure the SNR by using the matlab command

```
[peaksnr,snr] = psnr(I_my_noisy, Im)
```

I get SNR equal 10.
So, what is the wrong in my code? and why the result differ from my add dB?

Comment: I don't understand that part of the formula `var(Im(:))`. Why does your noise depend on the variance of the image?

Comment: I depend on the following post from this site

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008228/using-imnoise-to-add-gaussian-noise-to-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do:

```
Error = I_my_noisy - Im;
SNR = 10*log10(var(Im(:))/var(Error(:)));
```

You'll get the SNR you'd set up at the beginning. The thing is, it differs of the SNR you're computing with `psnr`. The difference is made on the way the function `psnr` measures the SNR.

If you see the source code of `psnr`, you'll see this 2 lines:

```
err = immse(A,ref);
snr = 10*log10(mean(ref(:).^2)/err);
```

In your case `immse(A,ref)` is equivalent to `var(Error(:))` because the noise is gaussian with zero mean. But `mean(ref(:).^2)` is not the same as `var(Im(:))` because `Im` doesn't have zero mean, so this operation isn't equal to variance.

This is why you're not getting the value you were expecting.

**EDIT:**

Anyway, the correct form of the SNR is the one measured in the `psnr` function because the SNR measures the power ratio between signal and noise and the way of calculating it is by `mean(ref(:).^2)`

Comment: Thank you @dubafek for your helpful answer.

I test your formula and as you said, I get like the setup answer, but according to your final paragraph, you advise me to use the matlab function psnr, because it is more accurate to measure the noise.

Comment: @serwan-bamerni I mean that using `mean(Im(:).^2)` is better than `var(Im(:))` because se first one measures the power of the signal. A definition of SNR can be found [here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/sage/soft/snr/). Note that if you divide by the number of elements, you get the expression used `psnr`