# MATLAB: What is the difference using imnoise and randn for Gaussian noise

Tags: image, matlab, signals, gaussian, noise

When adding additive white Gaussian noise in MATLAB, one can use the predefined function

```
J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',M,V) % I is the image to add the noise
```

with default, zero mean (M) and variance (V) 0.01. The manual for this function is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html).

However, in various MATLAB codes, I've also seen that additive Gaussian noise is added to the image by the following way

```
sigma = 10; % standard deviation (STD)

g = I + sigma * randn(size(I)); %add gaussian noise with STD 10
```

Which is fine. Now, we know the formula for variance,

```
[![variance=sigma^2][2]][2]
```

where sigma is the STD. So, according to the second code, I have sigma = 10 thus, the variance (V) should be 100.  Using MATLAB imnoise function for zero mean and variance 100 should be something like this

```
J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,100)
```

However, this does not produce a corrupted image even close to the second code. The image seems to be 100% corrupted with noise. How is this different ? am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I am seeing is that the `imnoise` function expects the image to be scaled to the interval `[0,1]` (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16011946/6158440)). Considering this, a variance of 100 makes no sense. You should scale the variance alongside the image and hopefully everything makes sense again.

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. Also, thanks for that link. It was helpful

Comment: A quick question though. So if i have an image with pixel value between 0 to 255 and want to add noise with sigma = 10, I can find the variance as, variance = sigma^2/255^2. Then using this to the imnoise function. Is that correct ?

Comment: @tarmizi Yes, that seems to be correct. The standard deviation should be scaled in the same way as the image (it has the same units in contrast to the variance) and then you get the variance by squaring.