# MATLAB: How to use imnoise(I, 'localvar', image_intensity,var)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am trying to add noise to an image that varies based on the intensity of an image.

```
I = imread(filename);
figure, imshow(I);

v = I(:);
J = imnoise(I, 'localvar', v, 0.04*v);
figure, imshow(J);
```

But when I run the algorithm, I get the following exception:

> error using max: Integers can only be combined with integers of the
>   same class, or scalar doubles

I'm not sure what my issue is either. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check `which I` and `which v`, are those the same class?

Comment: Do `I =im2double( imread(filename));` to convert to double

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you read `I` from the file in one format, and `imnoise` function uses different format. After reading `I`, write the following line:

```
I = double(I)
```

That would help you. Here is the whole example from a similar question:
 [Using imnoise to add gaussian noise to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008228/using-imnoise-to-add-gaussian-noise-to-an-image):

```
I = imread('eight.tif');
I = double(I);

%// Adjust intensities in image I to range from 0 to 1
I = I - min(I(:));
I = I / max(I(:));

%// Add noise to image
v = var(I(:)) / sqrt(10);
I_noisy = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, v);

%// Show images
figure
subplot(1, 2, 1), imshow(I), title('Original image')
subplot(1, 2, 2), imshow(I_noisy), title('Noisy image, SNR=5db')
```